# How can i control a collada model's animations with papervision3D?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, papervision3d, collada

How can i control a collada model animations with papervision3D? And why everthing i find for papervision3D is 2008 or 2009 dated? is this library death??

Answer (score 0):

You can control DAE animation by using [DAEMC2](http://tracehello.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/controlling-dae-animations-in-papevision3d/).